SCSI "WRITE SAME" and "COMPARE AND WRITE" over iSCSI
Which operating systems use "WRITE SAME" and "WRITE COMPARE" SCSI functions? I grepped through the Linux kernel code but as far as I could see they're only used for target-functionality there. Also the windows 10 initiator does not use them I believe.
And how are they triggered with normal use? E.g. with which regular file/disk i/o functions can I execute them?

I think it will depend on the Use Case and is more related to specific tasks and commands like in sg_write_same (sg3_utils) and dd command. And maybe some interesting information regarding WRITE SAME.

‘triggered with normal use’ I think this is the part you might be misunderstanding. These are specialized commands for very specific use cases, and outside of those very specific use cases there is no ‘normal use’ that can be expected to generate these commands.

Doesn't the SCSI-equivalent of TRIM (blkdiscard, fstrim) sometimes go through WRITE SAME (with the UNMAP bit set)?

VMware with VAAI and Windows Server with ODX make extensive use of the SCSIOP_WRITE_SAME (0x41) and SCSIOP_COMPARE_AND_WRITE (0x89) commands. You can use a software-based SCSI bus analyzer layered on top of the shared SCSI LUN to capture outbound SCSI traffic. Just ensure that you connect to a sophisticated iSCSI target that supports VAAI and ODX functionality.

See this VMware document.
The "COMPARE AND WRITE" is pretty straight SCSI equivalent of the VAAI high-level "Atomic Test and Set" operation, so that would be useful only with storage systems that are accessible with multiple computers at the same time. The typical use of the SCSI "COMPARE AND WRITE" function would be an optimization for a storage-based cluster lock manager, used when getting locks related to cluster metadata or shared cluster filesystems.
The Distributed Lock Manager included in Linux kernel is designed to also work on commodity hardware that might not support the SCSI "COMPARE AND WRITE" or equivalent atomic test-and-set function, so it has apparently solved the lock atomicity problem in some other way that doesn't need specific hardware support. (It is network-based instead of storage-based, for one thing.)
The "WRITE SAME" SCSI function is mostly applicable to overwriting/wiping large amounts of data, so you might expect to find it used in disk wipe tools, virtual disk initialization routines, and similar.
Both cluster lock managers and disk wipe/initialization tools generally tend to be designed for running as root, so issuing arbitrary SCSI commands from userspace code would not be a problem for them.

why is this reply considered not to be good?

My guess is, that it's because the text is clearly AI-generated.

@NISMO1968 English is not my first language, so sometimes I might slip into sentence structures of my native Finnish, especially if I'm tired (as I think I was when writing the above answer). And I know I sometimes write a bit too complex sentences. But that's the first time I've been called an AI!

You might accept this as a compliment!
